# Palindrome index in HackerRank

Tags: ruby, palindrome

I am solving a [palindrome index](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/palindrome-index/problem) problem from HackerRank as explained below.

Some heads-up will go along way. Thank you!

Here is my code:

```
# Complete the palindromeIndex function below.
def palindromeIndex(s)
  # slen = s.length
  splt = s.split('')

  n = s.reverse
  nsplt = n.split('')

  if n == s
    return -1
  elsif n != s 
    splt.each do |p|            
      if nsplt[p] != splt[p]
        return p
      end
    end
  else 
    return -1
  end
end
```

> In the first line, I am first splitting the given string and its respective reverse form. Then I am trying to compare the original string with the reversed string. if they are equal my program should return -1. If not I should loop through the initially split strings and check the indices for any indifference and return the position of the character different from the main string.

So far I am not sure I am having me right but I am also getting an error in my first attempt.

```
solution.rb:18:in `block in palindromeIndex': no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)
from solution.rb:17:in `each'
from solution.rb:17:in `palindromeIndex'
from solution.rb:34:in `block in <main>'
from solution.rb:31:in `times'
from solution.rb:31:in `<main>'
```

What could I be getting wrong here?

Comment: Your last `else` content is never called. `n` is either equal to `s` or not equal to `s`. Since both expressions are check for code will never reach the last `else`. I suspect you want to move that code up to after the `splt.each` loop. `return -1` would then be called when the loop finishes and didn't return during the loop process.

Answer (score 2):

```
splt.each do |p|
```

The above returns each of the characters in `s`, not the positions of the characters.  This is why you're getting the error... for "abba" you're doing `splt['a']` not `splt[0]`

If you want the position you can do each_with_index

```
splt.each_with_index do |_, p|
```

Since you don't need the character itself, we've assigned underscore `_` to it in the iteration.

Alternatively, you can use a range of integers

```
(0...splt.length).each do |p|
```

Note the use of THREE dots in the range, which means from zero up to one less than the length since a string of five characters will only have indicies from 0 to 4.

Or you can simply do the loop for the number of times there are characters...

```
splt.length.times do |p|
```

Comment: I would use [`splt.each_index`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-each_index) over `(0...splt.length).each`.

Comment: @3limin4t0r tmtowtdi :)

Comment: Don't forget about `split.length.times` which also iterates over the same range and looks a little better.